# Which controls to use for power automate workflow?

Tags: power-automate

I need some guidance, i have the following business logic but i am not sure which correct controls to use for my workflow in order this to function well. Basically i have 2 forms on sharepoint and have site name for these. Problem is on applying the correct controls that is in sync when form is created by the user.

`

```
`Create new NCR             
                    
    The auditor completes the NCR form and sets the work flow and clicks on Request Action              
                    
    Status: Request action              
                    
    An email is sent to the Responsible person with the link (NCR title)                
                    
    Responsible person completes corrective and Preventive action form, attach evidence and clicks on Submit for Approval/Restart Approval (round 2)                An email notification is sent to the responsible person. They correct as per the comments and  click on Restart approval
            Rejected, restart approval      
    1st Approver receives an email notification with a link (Title) and tabs for Approve, Reject, Reassign. The Approver clicks on the link and reviews the NCR and takes action Approve/reject     The 1st, 2nd,3rd approver reviews the NCR (2nd round) and approves/reject       If the 1st, 2nd & 3rd  approver rejects: a popup window that requires comments is activated. They complete the comment and reject)
                    
    Status: Submit for approval     Status: Rejected, approval restarted        
                    
    If approved, an email is sent to the 2nd approver, with a link and tabs to Approve, Reject etc. The send approver, approves     E-mail sent to the 2nd approver with a link and the 2nd approver reviews the NCR (2nd round) and approves/reject        
                    
                    
    Status: Submit for approval     Status: Rejected, approval restarted        
                    
    An email is sent to the SHEQ Manager for final approval and if he approves the status changes to Completed approved     An email is sent to the SHEQ Manager for final approval and if he approves the status changes to Completed approved     
                    
    Status: Completed approved      Status: Completed approved      
                    
    The record is created, all workflows are closed (no further notifications are sent out)     The record is created, all workflows are closed (no further notifications are sent out)     
`
```